# How to find OldPassword to let the user change it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm working on an intranet, I've just added a feature on the user's profile to change his password.

As you can see with the following controller :

```
[HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(Employee objToEdit, FormCollection form, LocalPasswordModel model) // Find how to obtain "OldPassword" from AccountModel
    {
        objToEdit.Login = User.Identity.Name;
        string name = objToEdit.FirstName;
        string pwd = form["NewPassword"];
        string confirm = form["ConfirmPassword"];

        if (_service.Edit_password(objToEdit, pwd, confirm)) // Checks if NewPassword and ConfirmPassword are the same, and does some syntax checking
        {
            bool changePasswordSucceeded;
            try
            {
                changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ResetPassword(WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(objToEdit.Login), pwd); // Seems to work                   
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                changePasswordSucceeded = false;
            }

            if (changePasswordSucceeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = CRAWebSiteMVC.Controllers.AccountController.ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
            }
            return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index"));
        }
        return View();
    }
```

So far, the user just needs to input a New password and a confirmation password. I wish to add a "Enter your current Password" feature but I **can't find a way to retrieve the user's current password !**

The user profile DB does not contain a Password column anymore and I use Form authentication if that's of any help.

EDIT: Thank you for your help, to solve my problem I simply replaced the ResetPassword line by the following :

```
changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(objToEdit.Login, current, pwd);
```

If it fails, it directly displays the error message that the current password is wrong.

Comment: Ask him the current, try to log it with the current password. If it fails it's the wrong one

Comment: `I can't find a way to retrieve the user's current password!` Fortunately!

Comment: Perhaps I didn't phrase it well, I wonder how I can add a way to make the user input his current pwd to let him change it. 
@Thomas, the user is already logged in since he changes his pwd from his profile

Comment: The same way you handle the login? I don't understand the problem, just look at the code of the login page.

Comment: you don't compare the password he entered with any password you stored plain. you compare the hash-stored password with the hash of the password he entered ;)

Comment: I understand, but how may I hash the input the same way it was hashed when he registered?

Comment: use the `PasswordHasher` class and a little bit of google :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't !

That's actually a security feature. You should never store a password in plain text.

The good thing is, you don't need to do the comparison yourself:

Instead, use something like [`ValidateUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.validateuser(v=vs.110).aspx) to let the Membership Provider validate the provided password. Behind the scenes, this method will hash the password and compare it with the hashed version contained in the database.

EDIT:

Also, note that since you are using the `WebSecurity` class, there is a method, [`ChangePassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.changepassword(v=vs.111).aspx) that accepts the current password. It seems that method will check the current password matches the specified `currentPassword` parameter. Maybe you should use this one instead of `ResetPassword`

Comment: I used ResetPassword because I did not have direct access to the current (old) password. As you have pointed out, I can't directly access it. I'll look into ValidateUser (that I can't seem to find for some reason).

Comment: The idea of the ChangePassword is that the current password need to be provided by the user as an input in a form! This is both a good practice, and a security feature. In fact, I thought that was your goal, since you stated _I wish to add a "Enter your current Password" feature_

Comment: Oh lovely, I guess I did not understand the good way to use ChangePassword. Thank you so much for your help, all I need to do now is find a way to display the error message next to the Password box !

Comment: I guess this would be taken care by the built-in validation mechanism.